# Framer motion whileHovering is not working for the mobile. For the animation to work on phone I have to define bunch of onclick listener?

Tags: reactjs, animation, frontend, framer-motion

Framer motion whileHovering is not working for the mobile. For the animation to work on the phone I have to define a bunch of onclick listeners?

So why use framer-motion for hovering I can do that using simple CSS and which will also work for mobile

Maybe I am missing something. So can anyone tell me what I should do

Comment: Instead of doing it with CSS, I use onMouseLeave and onMouseEnter properties. This saves me from defining a bunch of onClick functions. And it also works for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

try this on the div you're trying to animate

```
        whileHover={{
          opacity: 1,
          background: `url(${url})`,
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          borderRadius: 20,
          scale: 1,
          height: 277,
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          transition: { duration: 1 },
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: .5,
        }}

initial={{background: 'transparent'}}
```